# Bevel specific edges

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How would one curve specific edges while leaving others alone? I'm trying to model this (circled) object, But can't figure out how to bevel side edges and leave the front-edge flat.

[image]

Tried using the bevel modifier in combination with edge creases but that apparently has no effect, not sure what else to do, as I am still very new to modeling/blender.

[image]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Using the interactive bevel tool

You can select the specific edges you want to bevel (switch to edge selection mode to make this easier, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in *Edit* mode and select *Edge*) and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and drag to interactively adjust the bevel, additionally roll the scroll wheel to add in edge loops to round out the bevel. To bevel a single vertex, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

### Using the bevel modifier

Another way is to select the edges, add them to a vertex group from the *Object Data* panel and then use that group as input for the bevel modifier by choosing *Vertex Group* under *Limit Method*. This method is non-destructive meaning you can easily revert/make any changes by deleting the group or updating it.

[image]

**NB:** While you might select edges, the bevel modifier actually works on vertices so depending on your selections, results can vary. When using it, try to keep the edges connected and not spaced or leave gaps.

Comment: is this a bug? I copied the above example exactly("Using the bevel modifier"), except that I selected two adjacent edges, when adding the bevel modifier the whole top is beveled(all 4 edges). http://i.imgur.com/QpW9MLV.png

Comment: @kei Not exactly, there are no ___edge groups___ in Blender so it's actually beveling the vertices. For this I would recommend using weights instead.

Comment: If you don't have a mouse wheel, you can use the plus/minus keys to add/remove segments to/from the bevel.

Comment: I created a vertex group and then added a bevel to that particular vertex group.  I tested deleting the vertex group but the bevel did not disappear.  How can remove the bevel in a non destructive way using vertex group?

Comment: Is there any way to do this with Blender 3.3?

Answer (score 13):

On the bevel modifier, you can select *Weight:* as the application mode.  Then you can mark edges to bevel by changing their *Bevel Weight*, which is directly underneath the edge crease spinner on the right-hand toolbar of the 3D view.

You can also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and select bevel edges from there.  The downside to this is that changing the amount or undoing it is not as easy as simply editing or deleting a modifier.