# How to bevel selected edges

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a rectangular box where I want to add bevels to the four edges of the sides only.  I always get bevels on all edges. How do I restrice bevels to selected edges?  I'm just learning so need details. Thanks.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/bevel-specific-edges

Comment: If you're working with edges, switching to edge select will help as vertices have connections so you often won't get the result you want if these are close.

Comment: That was so simple.  I am struggling with shortcut keys, haven't found a good index yet. Thanks