# is there a way to smooth the objects without using ridiculous amounts of vertices or Subdivision Surface?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I am creating a model of a Warmachine Khador Juggernaut.

http://battlecollege.org/file/view/Juggernaut_09-CLPD.png/195178034/324x299/Juggernaut_09-CLPD.png

The mech I'm modelling has a lot of round edges and I want to eventually rig it.
My problem is that I want the model to look smooth, without it interfering with the vertices is there a way to smooth the lines between the vertices like in Illustrator?

Comment: I think subsurf is what you are looking for here. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Another way could be to bevel the interested edges with a round profile as shown in this related question [Bevel specific edges](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/bevel-specific-edges) (but you shold keep an eye on not messing up the topology)

Comment: Subsurface shrinks the area of the model and always gives me some really weird results, plus I only want certain areas to be smooth, while some areas like the axe I need to be really straight.  So, I need it to apply to certain vertices

Comment: @Batman_nerd See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6425/599. The techniques you're looking for come under the category of "hard surface modeling". I recommend trying out some [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+hard+surface+modeling) before starting on your own model