# A better way to make this car air vents holes?

Tags: topology

So I'm trying to make a firebird 68 but this air vents in the sides are causing me troubles with the topology, It's possible to do make this a better topology ?

Thanks in advance :D

[image]

Comment: or you can bevel your edges
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/bevel-specific-edges

Comment: I don't understand where I suppose to bevel

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Suggestions.  An increment in vertex density and use extrude.
The image above is an exaggeration of your subtle situation. Model progression.

Top Ortho.

- Loop Cuts.
- Delete Vertices and faces.
- Shape the hole manually, or with Proportional edit in Edit Mode, or with Loop Tools which is an addon.
- Extrusion marked by arrow and difficult to see

User Persp

- Extrusion allowing flexible shaping.  You are vents are somewhat like eyelids. They need less height. Add more loop cuts and shape subtly.

[image]

Still exaggerated for readability. Image above.  You can be more artistic with technical improvements.  This is an isolated modeling suggestion.  You can see models of hand and eyes to see how many loop cuts can be reused and reduced.

Comment: But if I increment the density It will be more dificult to control the circular shape where the tire go into don't you think ? or I'm worng ?

Comment: If you need a circular shape.  See the loop tools comment.  Also there are n-gons on which you can seek more opinions.