# How to create intermediate vertices of a humpy surface (interpolation)

Tags: vertices, edges, faces, interpolation

I took a cube, stretched it, added a number of intermediate edges and adjusted their height to get a humpy top surface.

Now, I want to get a smooth top surface by adding interpolated vertices. The existing edges must not change their position. How do I do this?

FYI: The object will be 3D-printed.

[image]

Comment: pics or it didnt happen

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/bevel-specific-edges

Comment: Is there any recommendation on how many intermediate steps to add? The object will be 3D-printed with a detail level of 0.1 mm.

Comment: more steps = smoother. depends on the look you are going for. here is the ruler tool https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/ruler_and_protractor.html and you can change the units http://eastmanreference.com/how-to-set-blender-to-metric-or-imperial-units/

Comment: I just tested it. Unfortunately, the existing edges don't stay where they were. They must not change their position!

Comment: If I could just get _one_ interpolated edge between every pair of existing edges with respect to the overall hump, I could use the bevel tool thereafter on the added edges.

Comment: I think in this situation you may start by modeling with nurbs (for the top part only) then convert it into mesh and a redo the other part from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eromod's hint was the solution.

- I created a huge ovoid (an icosphere that I compressed on one axis for an additional hump on the other axis),
- aligned it carefully manually,
- extended the original top surface in top direction,
- applied a boolean modifier with "Intersect" operation,
- and did a bit afterwork on the mesh.

*Please leave a comment if there's something I forgot to do proper preparation for rounded edges around the top surface.*

[image: Result]

Comment: Could you please clarify what is "huge ovoid" and "intersection modifier" ? Does the latter mean `Ctrl`+`F` > *Intersection (Knife)* ? Also please don't include new question in the answer; ask a new question instead.

Comment: To me, you may have problems with triangles on the lateral faces when printing

Comment: Hm, (1) I'm only seeing triangles at the top, (2) the object will be 3D-printed at 0.1 mm with the SLS method (powder + laser) in nylon, which is quite good. So, I can't unterstand what effect you're referring to.

Comment: I think the faces will be triangulated. This is not visible in your image here, but enter edit mode, select all the vertice then ctrl+T. I am not a specialist, but I am quite sure the 3D printer will translate it like that. To tell it in other way, lateral faces are big ngons. You may ask about that using another question.

Comment: I see what you mean. I hope it gets resolved when rounding the edges around the top surface.

Answer (score 0):

hold  <kbd>shift</kbd> , select the opposing edges of a face, press  <kbd>W</kbd>  and choose  <kbd>subdivide</kbd> . This will split a face in two.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html#two-opposite-quad-edges

Comment: I moved all the comments to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43411/discussion-on-answer-by-eromod-how-to-create-intermediate-vertices-of-a-humpy-su), because it was getting quite long. Feel free to keep your discussion going in there.