# How to bend top part of the mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Im trying to make a fireplace so I want to bend the top part of the mesh upwards and I have no idea how to.

The bending i want to make on the mesh.

[image: ][1]]

Comment: Please tell us more. What do you need it for? High quality render? Low poly mesh? Please add some images with desired effect.

Comment: See if this helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60239/how-to-round-the-edges-of-this-object/60242#60242