# Curving an edge of a polygonal mesh in blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I'm trying to replicate this bat:

https://www.amazon.in/DSC-Scorer-Kashmir-Willow-Cricket/dp/B014R90AJA/ref=sr_1_11?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1544122892&sr=1-11&refinements=p_n_pct-off-with-tax%3A2665401031

This is what I've done till now:

[image]

Now I want to curve the edges in a way similar to the reference image. How do I do that?

Beveling the corners isn't what I want. I need the highlighted edge to be curved similar to the path curve alongside it:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round the edges of this object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60239/how-to-round-the-edges-of-this-object)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've edited the question to explain why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Use proportional editing. Here is a tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrNVVHdKd3E&t=1s

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible you've simply got too many polygons at too early a stage to get smooth curvatures easily?

This illustration may not be exactly what you're looking for, but shows the kind of variation you can get from a Bevel modifier and subdivision:

[image]

1. Shows the mesh. A 2-segment  Bevel modifier is assigned, by weight. The weights on various edges are adjusted to increase/decrease the intensity of the crease after subdivision (The *lower* the weight, the sharper the crease, relative to the base bevel width set in the modifier)
2. Shows the Bevel modifier applied: what it's actally done
3. 4,5 Show the result after 2x Catmull-Clark Subdivision.

I haven't gone all the way here - you could apply the Bevel, and go in to tweak the topology to remove any residual pinching, etc.

Comment: This is clearly the kind of way it should be modeled nowadays: As fewer vertices as possible. Such simple shape shouldn't require 2k vertices to make.