# How to make a edge of an object curved (I don't think I'm saying that right but please help!)

Tags: edges

I am very new to blender and am trying to make a model for a game called gmod. I am wondering how do I make an edge curved (I don't think I'm saying that right) as seen below.
[image: Inside the red circle is the edge I want to make curved]

Oh and if I add a subdivision surface modifier it does this:
[image: Idk]

Comment: start by adding a subsurf modifier

Comment: You want to bevel the edges, @JurassicGlitch , see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/bevel-specific-edges

Answer (score 2):

You could need both subsurf and/or bevel, depending on what you need.

Here's an example, starting from a box extruded and shaped to a similar starting object:

[image]

the edge trick is shown on the right wireframe: adding edges near subsurfed rounded corners, you get somewhat sharp edges if you need them, but leaving subsurf for the rest of the mesh...

Hth